# Difference in the value of evaluation-metric in xgb.train() and predict in R

Tags: classification, xgboost, model-evaluations

I have trained a xgboost classifier with a custom metric (f1_xgb), that is, the F1 score. Here the important aspect is that I evaluated the classifier on the ***test set*** by setting:

```
`dtrain <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(x_train), label = y_train)
dval <- xgb.DMatrix(data = as.matrix(x_test), label = y_test)
watchlist <- list(train = dtrain, test = dval)`
```

After the training, I used the `predict()` function on the SAME set (`x_test`). I would expect the same F1 score. Instead, the result was different (I used the F1 function from the MLmetrics package:

```
f1 <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) { 
  f1_val <- MLmetrics::F1_Score(y_pred = data$pred,
                                y_true = data$obs,
                                positive = lev[2])
  c(F1 = f1_val) 
}
```

).
However, the strangest aspect was a pattern involving the two F1 values as I adjusted the early_stopping parameter during the training.
Here is the custom metric for the evaluation of the classfier:

```
f1_xgb <- function(preds, dtrain) { # defining custom metric


labels <- getinfo(dtrain, "label")
   tp <- sum((preds > 0.5) & (labels == 1))
   fp <- sum((preds > 0.5) & (labels == 0))
   fn <- sum((preds <= 0.5) & (labels == 1))
   precision <- if (tp + fp == 0) 0 else tp / (tp + fp)
   recall <- if (tp + fn == 0) 0 else tp / (tp + fn)
   f1 <- if (precision + recall == 0) 0 else 2 * precision * recall / (precision + recall)
   return(list(metric = "f1", value = f1))
 }
```

1. First attempt: no early_stopping, 1000 iterations:

> 

```
set.seed(20)
 xgb_tuned3 <- xgb.train(params = params,
                         data = dtrain,
                         nrounds = 1000,
                         print_every_n = 100,
                        eval_metric = f1_xgb, maximize = T,
                        # early_stopping_rounds = 200,
                        watchlist = watchlist 
)

[1] train-f1:0.000000   test-f1:0.000000 
[101]   train-f1:1.000000   test-f1:0.000000 
[201]   train-f1:1.000000   test-f1:0.095238 
[301]   train-f1:1.000000   test-f1:0.095238 
[401]   train-f1:1.000000   test-f1:0.095238 
[501]   train-f1:1.000000   test-f1:0.181818 
[601]   train-f1:1.000000   test-f1:0.181818 
[701]   train-f1:1.000000   test-f1:0.181818 
[801]   train-f1:1.000000   test-f1:0.181818 
[901]   train-f1:1.000000   test-f1:0.181818 
[1000]  train-f1:1.000000   test-f1:0.181818
```

After all the iterations I get `test-f1:0.181818.`

```
 validation_probabilties3 <- predict(xgb_tuned3, as.matrix(x_test))
 validation_prediction3 <-(validation_probabilties3 > 0.5)
 
 f1_df <- data.frame(obs = as.factor(y_test), pred = as.factor(as.numeric(validation_prediction3)))
 f1_model <- f1(f1_df, lev = c("0", "1"))
 f1_model
             F1 
0.2608695652174
```

As I said, the F1 value for the predicted values is higher than `test-f1`.

2. Second attempt: early_stopping = 200

   ```
   set.seed(20)
     xgb_tuned3 <- xgb.train(params = params,
                             data = dtrain,
                             nrounds = 1000,
                             print_every_n = 100,
                            eval_metric = f1_xgb, maximize = T,
                            early_stopping_rounds = 200,
                            watchlist = watchlist 
    ) 


   [1]  train-f1:0.000000   test-f1:0.000000 
        Multiple eval metrics are present. Will use test_f1 for early stopping.
        Will train until test_f1 hasn't improved in 200 rounds.

    [101]   train-f1:1.000000   test-f1:0.000000 
    [201]   train-f1:1.000000   test-f1:0.095238 
    [301]   train-f1:1.000000   test-f1:0.095238 
    Stopping. Best iteration:
    [159]   train-f1:1.000000   test-f1:0.095238 

    > validation_probabilties3 <- predict(xgb_tuned3, as.matrix(x_test))
    > validation_prediction3 <-(validation_probabilties3 > 0.5)
    > f1_df <- data.frame(obs = as.factor(y_test), pred =
   as.factor(as.numeric(validation_prediction3)))
    > f1_model <- f1(f1_df, lev = c("0", "1"))
    > f1_model
                 F1 
    0.1818181818182
   ```

Here the F1 score is again higher, but is the SAME as the `test-f1` value that I obtained in the first attempt (`test-f1:0.181818`)!

Third attempt: early_stopping = 50

```
  > set.seed(20)

> xgb_tuned3 <- xgb.train(params = params,
+                         data = dtrain,
+                         nrounds = 1000,
+                         print_every_n = 100,
+                         eval_metric = f1_xgb, maximize = T,
+                         early_stopping_rounds = 50,
+                         watchlist = watchlist 
+ )
[1] train-f1:0.000000   test-f1:0.000000 
Multiple eval metrics are present. Will use test_f1 for early stopping.
Will train until test_f1 hasn't improved in 50 rounds.

Stopping. Best iteration:
[1] train-f1:0.000000   test-f1:0.000000
```

The evaluation metric value here is 0

```
> validation_probabilties3 <- predict(xgb_tuned3, as.matrix(x_test))
> validation_prediction3 <-(validation_probabilties3 > 0.5)
> 
> f1_df <- data.frame(obs = as.factor(y_test), pred = as.factor(as.numeric(validation_prediction3)))
> f1_model <- f1(f1_df, lev = c("0", "1"))
> f1_model
             F1 
0.0952380952381
```

As expected at this point, the F1 score for the predicted values is the same I obtained during the attempt 2 training phase. I cannot really understand what is going on. Am I missing something obvious here?